# Android canvas get cleaned when using many path and paint object

Tags: android, canvas, path, ondraw

Can someone explain me why on earth this piece of code does not draw every object?

```
public class A extends View {
private Paint paint = new Paint();
private Path path = new Path();
ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>> paths = new ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>>();


public A(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (Pair<Path, Paint> p : paths) {
        canvas.drawPath(p.first, p.second);
    }
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}



@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float eventX = event.getX();
    float eventY = event.getY();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3f);

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            int color = Color.rgb(new Random().nextInt(255),
                                new Random().nextInt(255), 
                                new Random().nextInt(255));
            paint.setColor(color);
            path.reset(); //new stroke, get old one erased
            int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
            for (int i = 0; i > historySize; i++) {
                path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
            }
             path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);

            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
            // End of stroke, add this to the collection
            paths.add(new Pair<Path, Paint>(path, paint));
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    // Schedules a repaint.
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

}

I'm catching every strokes with the onTouchEvent and i create different path/paint ojects stored in a Pair one. Sadly in my OnDraw when I try to draw them all it fails .. 
I've read some topic without finding right answer. Each time some people recommend to create and work in a bitmap and draw it to the screen but i'd like to avoid this solution.

Thank's for your help !

Comment: the problem is that you always use the same `Path` and `Paint` object. You should create new `Path` and `Paint` when `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` is fired.

Comment: vmironov, you're my Hero ! I've been stuck for almost two days on that problem! I've added paint=new Pain(); and path=new Path(); on MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and now it works. Well i though everything was copied in java, not referenced so i thought object in my pair was different each time ... Thank you !

Comment: it's great you get it working! I've posted my comment as an answer, so you can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you always use the same `Path` and `Paint` object. You should create new `Path` and `Paint` each time `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` is fired

Comment: How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the path.reset in switch condition. The draw works. But color does change even for previous draw. You resetting the paths which is clearing the previous draw.

I would use a different pair (path and paint) everytime to draw.

In case you want to draw using canvas the below code work's just fine.
I would also add a color picker to allow user to pick color of his choice.

```
  public class MyView extends View {

    private static final float MINP = 0.25f;
    private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;

    private Bitmap  mBitmap;
    private Canvas  mCanvas;
    private Path    mPath;
    private Paint   mBitmapPaint;

    public MyView(Context c) {
        super(c);

        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }
    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SCREEN));
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Raghunandan. vmironov helped me to resolve my problem. I think i've already seen this kind of implementation but in my case i didn't want to use a bitmap. Anyway thank you for the sample, i'll take a closer look later, when i'm back home :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use only one Path and Paint object.

A detailed tutorial on this whole thing can in fact be found here: 
[Making a basic single touch drawing app on Android - Creative Punch](http://creative-punch.net/2014/03/make-basic-single-touch-drawing-app-android/)

Comment: Thank you for the example. But actually i need to store all stroke as pathes, not only draw the touches on a canvas.